# iOS - Push viewController from code and storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xcode4.5, pushviewcontroller

I have this code

```
 PlaceViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceView"];
 [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And I can change view, but I would push this view for when I return at this page, the state persists.

I try to put this code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

but doesn't do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 41):

**Objective-C:**

```
PlaceViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

Please do notice below points,

1. your storyboard identifier is correct.
2. The root view have navigation Controller.

**Swift:**

```
let newView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyBoardIdentifier") as! PlaceViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newView, animated: true)
```

Comment: hi here in destination viewcontroller don't getting navigation

Comment: @JigneshB: Do you connect with  navigation controller ? check 2nd point, 2. The root view have navigation Controller.

Answer (score 6):

For Storyboards, you should use `performSegueWithIdentifier` like so:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier goes here" sender:self];
```

Comment: Where? (Sorry for not knowing)

Comment: Instead of `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];` you should use `[self performSegueWithIdentifer:@"You identifier" sender:self];`

Comment: "No visible @interface declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifer:sender'"
I have this error

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier is a method of the UIViewController class. Unless your ModelController is a sub class of UIViewController the method will not be available. Without understanding your application fully it's not possible to be certain

Comment: i suggest you to read http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 this tutorial

Comment: I call this code from this class: "@interface MapViewController : UIViewController {...}" so, this class is a subclass of UIViewController right?

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:nil];
PlaceViewController *newView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceView"];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:nil];
PlaceViewController *newView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.x**

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") as! UIViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -2):

By default, Xcode creates a standard view controller. we first change the view controller to navigation controller. Select the Simply select “Editor” in the menu and select “Embed in”, followed by “Navigation Controller”
Step 1. Select Main story board
Step 2.Click on "Editor" on top of your Xcode application.
Step 3. Click  on "Embed In"

Xcode automatically embeds the  View Controller with Navigation Controller.