# Redirect to new ViewController after Facebook Login

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have added the Facebook iOS SDK into my xCode Project so it allows a user to login. However, once the user has logged in, in the same viewcontroller, their information is simply updated from their profile and the Login button changes to Logout.

However, I want the user to be redirected to DashboardViewController if login is successful. How would I do that?

Here is my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "FriendsViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.facebook = [self.delegate facebook];
    self.facebook.delegate = self;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.loginButton setTitle:[self.facebook loginLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.userProfileImage.profileID = [self.facebook userProfilePicture].profileID;

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

        // Yes, so just open the session.
        [self.facebook login];
    }
}

- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender
{
    if([self.facebook status] == logOff)
    {
        [self.facebook login];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.facebook logout];
    }
}

- (void)loginFacebookStatusUpdate
{
    [self.loginButton setTitle:[self.facebook loginLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.userProfileImage.profileID = [self.facebook userProfilePicture].profileID;
    self.userProfileLabel.text = [self.facebook userProfileName];
    self.userProfileBirth.text = [self.facebook userProfileBirthday];
}

- (void)getFriends:(id)sender
{


    if([self.facebook isLogged])
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *query = QUERY_USER_FRIENDS;

        [self.facebook submitQueryFQL:query error:error];
    }
}

- (void)fetchFQLQueryResult:(NSArray *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    self.friends = [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];

    FriendsViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FriendsViewController"];
    controller.friends = self.friends;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}



@end
```

Comment: You would redirect in the method called after the login has completed is the simple answer. There is a number of different ways to redirect based on the location of DashboardViewController. Is it another tab in a tabbarcontroller? Is it somewhere in a UINavigationController stack? It all depends on where it is in relation to ViewController.

Comment: it is a separarte view controller, not in tabbar, set up in StoryBoards

Comment: So you just want to push to it after the user logs in? Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987026/ios-push-viewcontroller-from-code-and-storyboard

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using FBLoginView for the facebook login. So once you have completed the login process you can redirect the user by the following method. And you need to give  to the loginView.

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
         dashBoardViewController *dashBoard = [[dashBoardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"dashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:dashBoard animated:YES];
}
```

And in the same manner you can handle the logout also by using the method

```
 - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
      // Your Code...
}
```

Hope, this will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible using facebook default function . Try this may be help full

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
      NSLog(@"email address %@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
     NSLog(@"Token Return %@",[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData);
     dashBoardViewController *dashBoard = [[dashBoardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"dashBoardViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:dashBoard animated:NO];
}
```

It's working fine & tested by me, Actually I have same work in my last project. Try it