# Segue 2 view controllers forward not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, segue

I have 3 `viewControllers`. `viewController1` is linked to `viewController2` (via segue id "first"), and `viewController2` is linked to `viewController3` (via segue id "destinationController"). I'm trying to segue from `viewController1` to `viewController3`. Here is my code:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

It crashed with the following error:

```
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fb1a944be00>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DestinationController''
```

How can I segue 2 `viewControllers` without connecting the first to the last? (I prefer not adding a segue from the `storyboard` because it will get very messy.)

Comment: You can't do that; a segue has to be connected in the stryboard.  But what you're doing in your code isn't a segue anyway. What you have, should work if viewController3 has the identifier "DestinationController".

Comment: vc2 is connected to vc3 with the identifier of DestinationController

Comment: I don't know how you could get the error you're getting then, because it's saying that you don't have a controller with that identifier -- I think what you have is a segue with that identifier. You need the identifier on the controller (storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector).

Comment: You hit it on the dot!! Thanks!!

Comment: Which way is recommended, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, or should I just add a segue from vc1 to vc3?

Comment: They do the same thing, but I would use a segue as it makes the navigation between your controllers clearer.

Comment: Thanks!! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Horray: " DestinationController" is your segue name or StoryBoardId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you  that you don't have a controller with the identifier, "DestinationController". From the text in your question, it seems that you have a segue identifier called "DestinationController", but that's a different thing from an identifier on the controller, which you set in the Identity Inspector with the "Storyboard ID" field.

I think it would be more consistent though, to make a segue from the first to the third view controller. It also makes the navigation among your controllers clearer in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please check "DestinationController" segue is bind with you current ViewController in which you write this code.

If you perform segue from VC1 to VC3 there is only one way in your case you have to go through VC2 (You can place conditions on viewDidLoad method of VC2 to perform segue with VC3).

Please bind "DestinationController" to your current controller and your error will gone.

This may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController3 *controller3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: controller3 animated:YES];
```

**Don't forget the set the storyboardId `"DestinationController"` not the segue name,** Check the below Link,

[Check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987026/ios-push-viewcontroller-from-code-and-storyboard/23907110#23907110)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but @rdelmar already answered the same thing. check his.