# Push view controller not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UINavigation` and `UIPageView` controller in a `UIViewController`. I have 3 buttons and here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)StartButtonClicked:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"start button pressed");
     [_Timer invalidate];
     _Timer = nil;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
         CardViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CardViewController"];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)pageViewController {
    self.pvc = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pvc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.pvc.view];
    [self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray1 objectAtIndex:0]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)rightButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self pageViewController];
    [self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray1 objectAtIndex:1]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)leftButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     [self pageViewController];
     [self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray1 objectAtIndex:2]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I click on right button and came back to this view controller my start button's push view not working.

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: when i click for the second time self.navigationController.viewControllers = null.

Comment: Why you are using 'setViewControllers' For push use the below answer code,[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourControllerObj animated:NO]

Comment: In storyBord initialize like the below image, then when push push by usig pushViewController and when back use popViewController. Don't change the NavigationController

Comment: i'm using setviewcontrollers for left/right buttons.. check the above code of mine..  is that wrong

Comment: Ok Sorry, Pls ignore the comment.

Comment: yes thats ok.. do u have any solution?

Comment: In the  'StartButtonClicked' what you are doing ? 1. Which is your rootView Controller 2. Where you are dispalying your PageViewController

Comment: start is to navigate to other view controller. And pageview is for leftButton action (navigate to another view)

Comment: Are you trying to use sideMenu like facebook or other apps ?

Comment: For push  you should use UIPageViewController .

Comment: no simple buttons

Comment: Push like this , UIPageViewController * controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UIPageViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];

Comment: OR you can set by using storyboard itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer .
[iOS - Push viewController from code and storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987026/ios-push-viewcontroller-from-code-and-storyboard)

Don't initialize Storyboard always,

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

You can set the rootViewController from the UtoryBoard itself.
Set initialViewController as a UINavigationController and Set the FirstViewController as RootViewController.

**Edit :**
For Push use the below code,

```
 CardViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CardViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

and Back. If use the default backButton not need to write  any code. 
If use are using custom backButton,

```
[self.navigationController popViewController];
```

Check 2 things,

1. Your storyboard identifier is correct.
2. The root view have navigation Controller.

Your StoryBoard should be like this,
[image]

Comment: In 'StartButtonClicked' you are initializing the storyBorad again. Not need to set storyBoard again. Set via main.storyBoard itself.

Comment: now i removed that line.. click on left/right button and navigate to other view controller and then click back button from that view and come back here (start button not working but left/right button working).. this is the scenario.

Comment: for push use the  code: CardViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CardViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO]; and for back use [self.navigationController popViewController];